# Quark model in particle physics; is it possible for a particle to exist with five or seven quarks?

Tags: standard-model, quarks, confinement, pentaquarks

As we all know that baryons are made up of three quarks while mesons are made up of a quark and an anti-quark. Is it possible for a particle to exist with five or seven quarks? Can a particle exist consisting of three quarks with color quantum no. (red,green and blue) and a quark and an anti-quark with opposite color quantum no. I am not sure if such a system will qualify for a pentaquark system.

Comment: The pentaquark is a hot topic since its discovery in the LHCb experiments
https://www.insidescience.org/blog/2015/07/21/party-five-physicists-discover-long-sought-%E2%80%98pentaquark%E2%80%99-stroke-luck

You might also interested in looking up for tetraquark

Comment: Phys.org: [New evidence from LHC shows pentaquark has a molecule-like structure](https://phys.org/news/2019-06-evidence-lhc-pentaquark-molecule-like.html), PRL: [Observation of a Narrow Pentaquark State, Pc(4312)+, and of the Two-Peak Structure of the Pc(4450)+](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.222001)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mesons and Baryons are the most common objects quarks make.
However, they are not the only ones.

There are tetraquarks (=4 quarks, in the form $qq\bar{q}{\bar{q}}$, due to color confinement), such as the Z(4430) confirmed by LHCb with a significance of 13.9$\sigma$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z(4430)) for relevant references.
The treatment of these objects theoretically is more difficult, and as they contain more quarks, they are generally with higher rest mass.

There are also proposed pentaquarks (=5 quarks, in the form $qqqq\bar{q}$, again, due to color confinement), and while two have been recently discovered in LHCb (See e.g. [this](http://lhcb-public.web.cern.ch/lhcb-public/Welcome.html#Penta)), there are some who disagree (Not on the quark content, but rather on classification), see e.g. [this](http://www.science20.com/a_quantum_diaries_survivor/marek_karliner_not_a_pentaquark_but_a_molecule_as_he_and_rosner_predicted-156535).

For information about color confinement, see any QCD textbook, or these two (For a less detailed explanation):
[About free quarks and confinement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45514/about-free-quarks-and-confinement)
http://pdg.web.cern.ch/pdg/cpep/color.html

So to summarize: Yes, such objects can exist, and we believe we have discovered a couple of them.

Comment: It might be helpful to clarify that a tetraquark is $qq\bar{q}\bar{q}$ and a pentaquark $qqqq\bar{q}$.

Comment: @dmckee You're right, I've noted that, and added color confinement references. (Though since OP knows about mesons and baryons, he should know this)

Comment: Phys.org: [New evidence from LHC shows pentaquark has a molecule-like structure](https://phys.org/news/2019-06-evidence-lhc-pentaquark-molecule-like.html), PRL: [Observation of a Narrow Pentaquark State, Pc(4312)+, and of the Two-Peak Structure of the Pc(4450)+](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.122.222001)