# How to understand that the strong nucleair force his reach is so short?

Tags: strong-force

I thought that de radius of the strong force is about 1/r7. The elekctromagnetic and gravity force is with a radius of about 1/r2. I understand that for those last ones twice as far away gives a four times weaker radiation per surface and three times further away gives a nine times weaker radiation per surface. It is good to understand.

But how can you explain that such a strong force loose so fast of its strength? Does it have somthing to do with the fact that the gluons creating the force are so different from photons?

Comment: Are you talking of the force between nucleons, protons and neutrons? Those are spill over forces from the strong force, like the Van der Waals forces for electromagnetism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the stronge force does not diminish with distance. 
When you pass a certain length, it stays fixed in a figure, about 10.000 Newtons.

related : [About free quarks and confinement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45514/about-free-quarks-and-confinement)