# What is quantum confinement in simple terms?

Tags: confinement

I have read quite a few explanations of [quantum confinement](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=quantum+confinement), but did not understand them. I have only a beginning understanding of quantum mechanics.

What is quantum confinement in the simplest terms possible?

Comment: Please indicate what *exactly* you don't understand about what you've read. Some explanations cannot be made any more simple without them becoming factually incorrect.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: Do you mean *confinement* as in the strong force? If so see [About free quarks and confinement](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45514/) or [search this site for more related posts](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=quark+confinement).

Comment: I believe this term is usually used in the context of materials science or solid state physics. Here's a Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_well.