# Why has there never been measured a free quark or gluon, but only objects that are built out of them, such as mesons and baryons?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, confinement, gluons

Why do we not observe any free quarks or gluon, but only particles that are built out of them, such as mesons and baryons? How does this phenomenon emerge from QCD?

Comment: Its known as color confinement.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45514/2451 and links therein.