# How does mass of the exchange particles affect the range of a force?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, photons, strong-force, gluons

I read an article asserting that nuclear force is a short range force because of gluon's mass, and EM force is a long range force because photons massless. 
I also want to know, why quantum confinement is a consequence gluon's mass?

Comment: Hi Aravindh. See the question I've linked for a derivation of the range/gauge boson mass relationship. NB gluons are massless. Confinement is not related to the mass of the gauge boson. It occurs because unlike photons the gluons are charged.

Comment: Thank you very  much. But Please man, elucidate quantum confinement and its reason

Comment: [See for example this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/45514/about-free-quarks-and-confinement). Or [search this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=quark+confinement) for lots more related posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question can be reframed, gluon and photon both are massless. In a general statement, one can say that interaction range $\propto$ 1/( gauge bosons mass). That is true for electromagnetism and electroweak both. But in case of QCD though gluons are massless the interaction is short ranged. This is the interplay between abelian nature of the theory and confinement. There is no direct relation between confinement and gluon mass (As far my knowledge is concerned).

Comment: Although gauge invariance implies that gluons should be massless, the lightest glueball is massive.  "What glueball?" you ask.  Something that mixes with neutral mesons, so QCD-ists presume.

Comment: "1/( gauge bosons mass)" that is a wrong statement for zero mass bosons i.e. photons and gluons.  Only for massive ones, the reason being that the propagator in the integrals calculating crossections are 1/(Q^2-M^2 +iε) .It is only when Q is smaller than M that the M dominates. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Propagators_in_Feynman_diagrams